# Как обратиться к tableView из другого класса?

Tags: objective-c, ios, tableview

У меня есть *view controller*  с *tableView* (объявлен как свойство класса *view controller*). Из класса `AppDelegate` нужно иногда обращаться к этому *tableView*, чтобы его обновить.
Как это сделать?

Comment: @Troir, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Почему не хотите использовать делегат (протокол). С другой стороны, у вас же вью контроллер выступает как рутконтроллер. Сделайте проперти таблицы не в инкапсуляции а в хидере контроллера. И потом будет что-то наподобие:

    [self.rootController.tableview reloadData].

Но опять же таки в будущем вам это может вылезти боком. Удачи.

Answer (score 1):

Точно-точно надо? Из *AppDelegate*? Обычно, так делать не надо.

Но вот вам несколько вариантов:
 1. Во *viewController* подпишитесь на событие `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver...]`, а в *AppDelegate* пошлите `notification [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification...];`.
 2. Храните ссылку в *appDelegate* на этот контроллер (но это вообще за гранью добра и зла).

Comment: Я примерно так и делал. А почему это плохой вариант?

У меня происходит следующее: приходит пуш сообщение, его надо обработать и добавить в tableView.

Все это сделать получается (при помощи observer) только мне надо, чтобы это все происходило даже в background mode (background моды включены), а этого не происходит, потому что observer активен только, когда само приложение активно.

Т.е. приходит пуш сообщение, и в таблице оно появляется, только если открыть приложение, а надо, чтобы оно открывалось уже обновленным.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это лучше реализовать.

Answer (score 0):

Делаешь *tableView public* и в *AppDelegate* `self.viewController.tableView.reloadData`

Comment: Спасибо, попробую.
Не понимаю, почему observer или ваш метод это считается быдло-кодом? Есть ли способы другие?

Comment: Быдло-код имеет один плюс, он всегда работает, и кучу недостатков.
В данном случае, если вы планируете дальнейшее развитие проекта, то это может Вам обойтись дорого по времени, используя обсерверы - фиг знает кто их обсервит, когда смотришь в код. В случае моем -  все классы имеют свои назначения и не стоит их путать, в данном случае AppDelegate ну ни как не должен отвечать за обновления tableView в каком-то там ViewController'e.. ну и так далее. MVC MVVM и прочие патерны проектирования нужны только для одного, для удобной поддержки, в будущем, кода.